# How to get Injection of broadcaster factory to work in atmosphere?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, atmosphere

I have to following code form here:
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-BroadcasterFactory-and-AtmosphereResourceFactory-with-2.2-and-newer

```
@Inject
@Named("/chat")
BroadcasterFactory factory;
```

But with jBoss EAP 6.4.7 it is not working, I can't deploy the war because of missing dependencies.

the beans.xml looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

And in the POM I have the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime-native</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-websockets</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried it without the `@Named` annotation?

Comment: Yes I have, it's the same problem.